# How wise is it from SEO standpoint to pick a business name that is picked before by another small business

Tags: seo, domains

After days of thinking and brainstorming to pick a name for my tech based startup I came up with a very simple and elegant name which is perfect except for it has already been picked by another very small UK based company (in construction industry) who owns the .net of this name.

the .com of it is also available for sale in aftermarket, but since my startup is tech based, and .io of the name is also available, I am thinking of getting that.

Now I am not concerned about this name being a trademark or that I face any other legal issues.

My only worry is that my decision today hurts SEO or my company's reputation in the long run.

Would you say it would be wise for me to pick this name?

Comment: "already been picked by another very small UK based company" - to clarify, are you also UK based?

Comment: The product is going to be introduced in North America.

Comment: This is impossible because when registering a global business, the registration institute checks at the global level for the presence of a duplicate legal name.

Answer (score 2):

If you make a specific content that is not related to the UK domain owner you are safe and you could rank with this name in the USA with no problem.

Just a good SEO strategy and you are ready to go.